# Potential bug : missing terms in ContinuedFraction

Tags: continued-fractions

If I use 0.23 instead of 23/100, the last continued fraction coefficient (7) is not given:

```
target = 23/100;
ContinuedFraction[target]        (* {0,4,2,1,7} *)
ContinuedFraction[N[target]]     (* {0,4,2,1} *)
FromContinuedFraction[%]         (* 3/13 *)
FromContinuedFraction[%%%]       (* 23/100 *)
% - %%                           (* -1/1300 *)
```

If I use something like 0.23001, the 7 will be there, and more coefficients after it; if I use something like 0.22999, there will be a 6 instead of the 7, and more stuff after the 6; but for plain 0.23, the 7 is just omitted, and the error of 1/1300 is whopping. It's not meant to be like that, is it?

**EDIT**

Ok, it's not a bug. Only the certain coefficients are being given, and in our case, the 7 is not among them, if `N[]` is used - see Chip Hurst's answer.

So I'd like to extend the question: If what I want is a result, such that the absolute difference between target and `FromContinuedFraction[result]` is smaller than a suitable epsilon, how do I make Mathematica give me that result, even if the last coefficient is uncertain?

(The issue appears to arise if and only if the input to ContinuedFraction is of the form `N[`rational number with smallish denominator`]` - in other cases, it seems, the "relevant" and the "certain" appear to coincide.)

Comment: Would [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) help?

Comment: sometimes - if the denominator is sufficiently small. For 0.23, it works fine.            
On the other hand, Rationalize[N[1352343/2010653]] doesn't perform as one would like (returns Head[]==Real). My bestGuessCF from my answer gives the coefficients of the exact fraction

Comment: You could also use `Rationalize[x, 0]` or `SetPrecision[x, Infinity]`.

Comment: Rationalize[SetPrecision[N[1352343/2010653], Infinity]] gives 6058142733606543/9007199254740992

Comment: Right -- it won't faithfully give back the original rational, but it will give an exact number very close to it. This means `ContinuedFraction` will give more terms.

Comment: Compare `N[FromContinuedFraction[ContinuedFraction[SetPrecision[N[1352343/2010653], Infinity]]] - 1352343/2010653]` and `N[FromContinuedFraction[ContinuedFraction[N[1352343/2010653]]] - 
  1352343/2010653]`.

Comment: Rationalize[x,0] does the trick. If you put that into a new answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It has similar drawbacks: `In[126]:= Rationalize[N[135234309348093840/2010653309839058], 0]

Out[126]= 1839217209/27345340`

Comment: No, it works. You have to use second argument of N to make computations more exact when you use such large numbers, but the Rationalize[..,0], or Rationalize[...,epsilon] is THE way to go on my extended question. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContinuedFraction[Rationalize[0.23, 10^-12]]  (* {0,4,2,1,7} *)
```

credit @ Chip Hurst / see discussion in question.

Comment: Hi Chip, I'll accept this own answer here (tomorrow), unless you want to have a go at summing up the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuedFraction.html#2144):

> ContinuedFraction stops when it runs out of precision

---

The numbers just left of `0.23` will have `6` in the continued fraction, and the ones to the right will have `7`. This means we can't know for sure which one to use, as `0.23` is not an exact number, and so it's dropped.

```
ContinuedFraction[23/100 - 1/10^20]
```

> ```
> {0, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9999999999999999, 7, 1, 2, 4}
> ```

```
ContinuedFraction[23/100 + 1/10^20]
```

> ```
> {0, 4, 2, 1, 7, 9999999999999999, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
bestGuessCF = Function[target, 
   With[{cf = ContinuedFraction[target], k = Unique["k"]},
    With[{cfx = Append[cf, k]}, 
     With[{ext = FromContinuedFraction[cfx]},
      With[{sol = Quiet[Solve[ext == target]]},
       If[Length[sol] > 0, cfx /. k -> Round[k /. sol[[1]]], cf]
]]]]];
```

Comment: this solution adds exactly one term to Mathematica's solution of the continued fraction, if the first term omitted by Mathematica is an "uncertain cliff hanger" thing, and leaves Mathematica solution unchanged otherwise.